# Uploading sas data set to teradata-Error:the value applied to a Teradata 2 byte decimal was out of range

Tags: sas, teradata

Got an error when uploading a sas dataset into teradata.ERROR: On an insert, update, or index operation, the value applied to a Teradata 2 byte decimal was out of range. This was the proc contents of the table

[image]

[image]

```
LIBNAME VKTD TERADATA SERVER='XXXXX' USER=&userid PWD=&pwd DATABASE ="db" MODE=TERADATA CONNECTION=GLOBAL;
/*Droping the table*/
PROC SQL NOERRORSTOP;
DROP TABLE VKTD.VK_FINAL;
QUIT;
PROC SQL;
 CREATE TABLE VKTD.VK_FINAL(TPT=YES FASTLOAD=YES TPT_MAX_SESSIONS=4 SET = YES DBCREATE_TABLE_OPTS='PRIMARY INDEX(column8,column6,column5)') AS
SELECT column1,column2, column3,column4,column5, column6,column7,column8, coloumn9 
FROM WORK.tablename;
QUIT;
```

Not sure which variable is causing the error and how to correct it.Column2 is decimal format 5.4

Comment: I'm not familiar with SAS/ACCESS to Teradata but Column2 might indeed be your culprit: with other ACCESS engines (e.g. SAS/ACCESS to Netezza), SAS uses the format in use for the column in the SAS table to determine the type of the column to create in the underlying DBMS (i.e., using a date format in SAS will make the difference between your DB column being created as a number or date type).

Comment: What are the values for "MODATE"?